# characters replace using vb.net 2012

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012

i have a program that replace **ing** in some string and its return original verb in that srting like **he was playing out door** will be **he was play out door** ...etc

> i just want the **play** without whole string

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

Dim myInput As String = TextBox1.Text
Dim myOutput As String = Replace(myInput, "ing", "")
Label1.Text = myOutput 

End Sub
```

Comment: `Dim newTxt = String.Join(" ", txt.Split(" "c).Select(Function(s) If(s.EndsWith("ing"), s.Substring(0, s.Length - 3), s)).ToArray())`  Of course if the string is "the king was playing with his ring outdoors" all sorts of extra changes happen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fastest way is to use a one-line Regex.

```
Dim Output As String = Regex.Match(myInput, "\p{L}+(?=ing[^\p{L}])", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase).Value
```

A `Regex` is a class capable of matching strings based on patterns. It's great to use and usually very fast. The pattern is the second string which I've passed to the `Match()` method. My pattern works like this:

The `\p{L}+` part means that it should match every character that is a unicode letter. `+` means that it should match one or more letters.

The `(?=ing[^\p{L}])` part means that the match must end with "ing", and that it's not followed by any unicode letters.

---

To match multiple verbs we'd have to expand this a bit. Putting it into a function. The function will find all substrings that match the specified pattern, and then put them in a string array and return it to you.

```
Public Function FindVerbs(ByVal Input As String) As String()
    Dim Matches As MatchCollection = Regex.Matches(Input, "\p{L}+(?=ing[^\p{L}])", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
    Dim ReturnArray(Matches.Count - 1) As String
    For x = 0 To Matches.Count - 1
        ReturnArray(x) = Matches(x).Value
    Next
    Return ReturnArray
End Function
```

**Function example usage:**

```
Dim Verbs() As String = FindVerbs("I am playing with my helicopter. It's flying very fast.")

Console.WriteLine(Verbs(0)) 'Prints "play"
Console.WriteLine(Verbs(1)) 'Prints "fly"
```

Example: http://ideone.com/6TeAmz

Comment: thanx for the help its the accepted answer ^_^ 
but what if there was more than 2 verbs ? like "he was playing and running" ? the output is just "play"


thanx for the help

Comment: @AmoshAmosh : If there are multiple verbs you have to use an array or a list of string. I will update my answer, since I'm going to include some explanation too.

Comment: @AmoshAmosh : I've updated the answer and the code. I will get back to you about multiple words in about 20 minutes (I'm quite busy).

Comment: i have read the explanation and its so amazing i understand everything now ,, and please take your time iam not in a hurry

thankss so much

Comment: @AmoshAmosh : Improved the pattern once more (last time, promise). I have now added how to get all verbs too!

Comment: ` Dim i As Integer = 0`
        `Dim Verbs() As String = FindVerbs("I am playing with my helicopter. It's flying very fast.")`

        `Do While (i < 0)`
            `Label4.Text = Verbs(i) 'Prints "fly"`
        `Loop`

 i do the loop to output the array in Lable but its not working !!

Comment: @AmoshAmosh : Use a `For` loop instead. It's much more efficient. See: http://pastebin.com/A3BuBQUm

Comment: yesssssssssssssssssss itssssss woooooooooorkeddddddd 

thaaaanx 4 the Amazing helpppppp :)

Answer (score 1):

```
Private Function getVerbOfSetence(ByVal str As String) As String
    Dim strSpl() As String = str.Split(" ")
    For i = 0 To strSpl.Length - 1
        If strSpl(i).ToLower.EndsWith("ing") Then
            Return strSpl(i).ToLower.Replace("ing", "")
        End If
    Next
    Return "noVerb"
End Function
```

Comment: Good answer, but you cannot replace `ing`. What if the verb is `ringing`? Remove the last three characters instead.

Answer (score 0):

Best way is to replace whole word. You put in word in textbox that you want to add ing to it

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

Dim myInput As String = TextBox1.Text
Dim myOutput As String = StringToReplacePart.Replace(myInput, String.Format("{0}ing", myInput)
Label1.Text = myOutput 

End Sub
```

Comment: But he didn't want to add "ing", he wanted to have the word _without_ "ing".